# How to show $E^0\subseteq E?$

Tags: real-analysis

Prove that  $E$ is open  if and only if $E^{0}=E$ ?

**My attempt** : to prove $E^{0}=E$ we must show that $E^0\subseteq E$ and $E^0\supseteq E$

To show  :$E^0\supseteq E$

proof : Suppose $E$ is open and $p \in E$ , then there exist $r >0$ such that $N(p,r) \subseteq E $ $\implies$ that $p$ is an interior point

therefore $p \in E^0$ .Hence $E^0\supseteq E$

Here im confused that how to show  $E^0\subseteq E?$

Comment: What is the definition of the interior of $E$?

Comment: @ShubhamJohri       $E^0$  is the largest open set  conatined in $E$

Comment: So does it not imply $E^0\subseteq E$?

Comment: oks  but we have to prove it

Comment: It is given to you as a definition. What is there to prove in a definition?

Comment: u r right  no need to proved it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here it is a proof in the context of metric spaces.

Let us prove the implication $(\Rightarrow)$ first.

Then we are assuming that $E$ is open. This means that $E\cap\partial E = \varnothing$.

Consequently, we have that
\begin{align*}
E = E\cap X & = E\cap(\text{int}(E)\cup\partial E\cup\text{ext}(E))\\\\
& = (E\cap\text{int}(E))\cup(E\cap\partial E)\cup(E\cap\text{ext}(E))\\\\
&= E\cap\text{int}(E)
\end{align*}

Hence we conclude that $E\subseteq\text{int}(E)$.

Once we always have that $\text{int}(E)\subseteq E$, we deduce that $E = \text{int}(E)$.

Indeed, if $p\in\text{int}(E)$, there is an open ball such that $B(p,r)\subseteq E$, whence $p\in E$.

We may now prove the implication $(\Leftarrow)$.

Therefore we have that $E = \text{int}(E)$.

Hence we have that $E\cap\partial E = \text{int}(E)\cap\partial E = \varnothing$

Thence we conclude that $E$ is open.

Hopefully this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Second inclusion is done by definition. *Interior of set $A$ is the largest open set contained in $A.$*